# 5 minute quickstart errors in app.component.ts

Tags: angular

I've been following the 5 minute quick start tutorial, and have run into a problem.

I received two errors in there terminal when compiling:

> app/app.component.ts(6,3): error TS1146: Declaration expected. [0]
>   app/app.component.ts(7,8): error TS1005: ';' expected.

I don't understand what the problem is. I have checked the file mentioned, and it is an exact copy of the tutorial.

**EDIT**

Resolved.

Either way, I found that I had misspelled `'export'` in :

`export class AppComponent { }`

I spelled export as `'expore'` and didn't catch the error until I just looked at it again after relaxing the past couple of hours.

Comment: How should we know, we have even less information. Can you create a Plunker?

Comment: At the end of the quck start tutorial on angular.io are all files and they are correct. If you copy these files to your dev envireonment you have a working project. If you compare your app.component.ts with the app component.ts from angular.io you will find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you add by mistake a `;` character at this end of the `@Component` decorator:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>'
}); // <--------------
export class AppComponent { }
```

This could throw such error.

Comment: I do not have the semicolon at the end of @Component.

Comment: Okay. Which version of TypeScript do you use to compile your code?

Answer (score -1):

Error may occur the `;` usage of end of `@Component`.
Changes may properly effected in your browser so please clear your browser cache always.